# Read XML NodeList

Tags: c#, xml

I am trying to parse an XML response from a REST call.  I can read the XML just fine with my stream reader but when I try to select the first node, it brings back nothing.  Here is my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="true"?>    
<slot_meta_data xmlns:ns2="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">    
    <product id="MDP">    
        <name>MDP</name>    
    </product>        
    <product id="CTxP">    
        <name>CTxP</name>    
    </product>       
    <product id="STR">    
        <name>STR</name>    
    </product>      
    <product id="ApP">    
        <name>ApP</name>   
        <slot>    
            <agent_id>-1111</agent_id>    
            <agent_name>ApP</agent_name>    
            <index_id>-1</index_id>         
            <alias>App Alias</slot_alias>     
        </slot>    
    </product>        
    <product id="TxP">    
        <name>TxP</name>        
        <slot>    
            <agent_id>2222</agent_id>    
            <agent_name>App2</agent_name>    
            <index_id>-1</index_id>    
            <alias>App2 Alias</slot_alias>      
        </slot>    
    </product>    
</slot_meta_data>
```

Here is my code

```
string newURL = "RESTURL";

HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(newURL) as HttpWebRequest;
HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;

StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());

XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();
xdoc.Load(response.GetResponseStream());

XmlNodeList list = xdoc.SelectNodes("/slot_meta_data[@*]");

foreach (XmlNode node in list)
{
    XmlNode product = node.SelectSingleNode("product");
    string name = product["name"].InnerText;
    string id = product["id"].InnerText;

    Console.WriteLine(name);
    Console.WriteLine(id);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

When I debug list, it has a count of 0.

Comment: There are no attributes on the `slot_meta_data` element... just a namespace declaration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using xml linq

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;


namespace ConsoleApplication22
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\TEMP\TEST.XML";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

            var results = doc.Descendants("product").Select(x => new {
                name = (string)x.Element("name"),
                slot = x.Elements("slot").Select(y => new {
                    agent_id = (int)y.Element("agent_id"),
                    agent_name = (string)y.Element("agent_name"),
                    index_id = (int)y.Element("index_id"),
                    slot_alias = (string)y.Element("slot_alias")
                }).FirstOrDefault()
            }).ToList();

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you. That works great.  So I tried to wrap this into a foreach loop to get them one by one.  I can get the product attributes (foreach (var result in results)) but when I try to get the slot attributes I get "object not set to an instance of an object".  I am using int agent_id = result.slot.agent_id

Comment: You don't need to wrap in a for loop.  Just enumerate the variable results in a for loop after the Linq.  Not all the products in the xml file have slots.  The 1st three product do not have slots, only the last two.

Comment: so I added an if to check for slot = null.  and then in else I added another foreach to loop through slots.  is this ok to do?